# Directive to add class to body in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I have the app like:

```js
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

I need to add class to the body but myApp is deeper than body.
I know that I can do it with window.body.addClass...

but I try to do it in an angular way

I try to create the Directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'body'
})

export class .... {
  @HostBinding('class.my-superBodyClass')
  public isShown: boolean = true;
}
```

And it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need to add a class to the body?

Comment: for example to add the theme like "dark" and "light"